# Developing a newspaper site in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I need to develop a newspaper site in Drupal, I've already played around with Drupal a little, and I think I know which modules would best suit my purposes. Naturally, one of the modules I'll be needing to use most is Views, but I have a couple of questions:

1. Because this is a content-intensive site, I was wondering if using 5-6 views on each page to generate node teaser + thumbnail lists would impact performance adversely?
2. I am a designer with significant front-end development experience. Like I said I've played around with Drupal quite a bit and other than running into a few hurdles which I eventually overcame, for the most part I was able to get it to do what I needed it to. Having said that, does one also need strong programming skills to fully develop a site in Drupal?

Thank you very much for your help!

Jane

Comment: A little PHP knowledge can go a long way when developing a Drupal site. Theming modules is something you'll inevitably find yourself wanting to do. I'm no PHP expert whatsoever but just by looking at the existing code and understanding what does what (as well as referring to the excellent php.net) I've managed to achieve everything I want from the site I'm currently developing so far.

Comment: Jane: While I can't talk a ton about how we do things I'd be happy to chat with you privately. I'm lead developer for a newspaper site with 8 digit monthly page views. E-mail to tylere@gmail.com and I'll get in touch.

Answer (score 0):

1. Views offers caching and Drupal also has block caching, which should help you improve performance. The SQL that Views generates is never as good as handwritten SQL, but if you make simple Views, the SQL is actually quite good and not a performance problem (unless you have millions of page views).
2. If you can create the features you need, with modules from Drupal.org, you don't need **strong** developer skills. But you do need to know some PHP to make a Drupal theme which is what controls the layout of the site. It will also be a great help, in understanding the Drupal theming system, but not a requirement.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your response! It is very helpful, and quite reassuring! :-)

Answer (score 0):

First off, check out [openpublishapp.com](http://openpublishapp.com) for a Drupal distro that is made for publishers from the ground up, it's pretty hot.

To answer your questions:

1) As far as performance and views goes, having 5-6 views on a page is a normal requirement for a drupal news site and the performance issues are usually handled by views/panel cache, and using a page cache like [Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/) in front of a web server, Object caches like [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) (for the DB) and opcode caches like [APC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators)...if you don't want to learn all that off the bat you should still be fine if your traffic isn't too intense (but go sign up at [getpantheon.com](http://getpantheon.com) for awesome hosting with all of that and the kitchen sink, and check out [groups.drupal.org/pantheon](http://groups.drupal.org/pantheon))

2) If the functionality exists by way of core/contrib modules, to fully develop a site for the most part one only needs to understand enough PHP to theme, and often with starter themes like [Fusion](http://drupal.org/project/fusion), and some of the others you hardly even need that, just an understanding of how they work and are extended (which is well documented). That said, if you want functionality that doesn't exist, you'll have to code it, or have someone code it for which strong programming skills are desired, but not necessarily required :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, jpstrikesback! I was actually able to fully theme a site just using HTML, CSS and with PHP print commands to output Drupal variables where they needed to go, so I'm hoping that won't be too much of a problem for this site. As far as visitors are concerned, I don't expect millions, but according to the people running the paper, 50,000 or a little more is quite likely... Thanks again -- so glad I posed my question here! :)

Comment: 50k is healthy :) If it's part of your scope I would make sure the hosting is up to the task, I recommend looking into the GetPantheon/Pantheon project or contacting Acquia or Rackspace for managed hosting, your views are going to cost something (in performance) and so you will want a reverse proxy cache (like Varnish) infront of the web server and a object cache like Memcached in front of the DB

Comment: Will definitely check them out! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Even I recommend the use of the OPENPUBLISH - https://www.acquia.com/solutions/publishing

On top of to this you can make an efficient usage of

```
 1. APC - PHP byte-code caching 
 2. Drupal Caching - block/template/view level caching
 3. Boost - Caching module which doesn’t need any external tools
 4. Varnish - HTTP accelerator
 5. Memcache - Data intensive content.
```

Apart from this you will also need to think effectively on deciding on DEPLOYMENT ARCHITECTURE of the site - preferably Acquia or Amazon environment.

Learning curve may vary depending on your current skills in PHP or Drupal. Usage of already established distribution like OPENPUBLISH may help you to minimize the dependability on too much custom coding.